# how to create an array of JSON objects , store them in a state array object and print the elements inside the render function in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

```
I am making a call to firebase database and parsing through the JSON objects and storing them in an array locally. Then I am copying the array created to a state array object and later printing the values of the state array object inside the render() function.



class ABC extends Component
    {

    state = {
    objectArray:[
     {
       key1:'',
       key2:'',
       key3:'',
       key4:''
     }
    ]
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        var objectArray = [];
        var object = {
             key1:'',
             key2:'',
             key3:'',
             key4:''
            };

    // parsing through the firebase object and storing it in the object which is happening successfully

    objectArray.push(object);
//when I print the array it gives me the result: [object Object],[object Object] which means two objects are getting stored here.

    this.setState({objectArray: objectArray });

    }

    render()
    {

    this.state.objectArray.map(function(item){
    console.log("The items is "+item.key1); // No data getting printed here.
    console.log("The items is "+item.key2);
    console.log("The items is "+item.key3);
    console.log("The items is "+item.key4);
    });

    }
```

I am able to fetch the results from the firebase object array and parse through them and store them in the objectArray local object but not able to store them inside the state array object. What is getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your render method should look like something as follows because you need to return some JSX.

```
render() {

  this.state.objectArray.map(function (item) {
    console.log("The items is " + item.key1); // No data getting printed here.
    console.log("The items is " + item.key2);
    console.log("The items is " + item.key3);
    console.log("The items is " + item.key4);
  });

  return this.state.objectArray.map(item => <p>{item.key1}</p>)

}
```

Note that all the values are empty strings so make sure that they're not.

**Update:**

From what I see in the file you provided, I guess you're setting the state before you actually receive the data. Try setting the state inside the callback:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const objectArray = [];
    const object = {
        key1: '',
        key2: '',
        key3: '',
        key4: ''
    };

    objectsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            objectsRef.child(childSnapshot.key).on('value', function (childData) {
                object.key1 = childData.val().key1;
                object.key2 = childData.val().key2;
                object.key3 = childData.val().key3;
                object.key4 = childData.val().key4;
                objectArray.push(object);
                this.setState({ objectArray: objectArray });
                console.log("objectArray array is " + objectArray.toString());
            })
        });

    });
}
```

It's better if you modify this such that the `setState` is only called once instead of for each iteration.

Comment: it is still not printing anything either in the console.logs or in the JSX elements.

Comment: @shikher.mishra - Are you able to see `"The items is "` in the console?

Comment: When the app loads the first time, the render function is executed, I am able to see it as all the values are initialized to null in the state object, but when the componentDidMount() function is executed and the data is fetched from the database, even "The items is" is not getting printed.

Comment: Since the code you posted in the question isn't the same, I can't help you without looking at the actual code.

Comment: https://ws.onehub.com/files/azh5egd4
This link contains the full code, please have a look.

Comment: the 'object' variable needs to be declared inside the loop, else the 2nd object in the list will be stored in the array twice.

Comment: @shikher.mishra - Yeah obviously adjust the code as you want. I've just added the reason for your state issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
this.state.objectArray.map( (item)=> return {
    console.log("The items is "+item.key1); // No data getting printed here.
    console.log("The items is "+item.key2);
    console.log("The items is "+item.key3);
    console.log("The items is "+item.key4);

  })
```

Comment: Still not printing anything.

Comment: What does your `this.state.objectArray` print?

Comment: on doing : console.log("The array is again: "+this.state.objectArray.toString); inside the render function I get:

The array is again: function toString() {
    [native code]
}

Comment: What did console.log("objectArray array is "+objectArray.toString()); print when you're iterating over `        objectsRef.on('value', ( snapshot ) => {
`

Comment: Saw the code. However, ` objectsRef.on('value', ( snapshot ) => {` this can not be stimulated since it's dependent on `db.ref('objects/');`